# a table of multiple values was supplied in 2012 SSAS tabular

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I am having hard time using case statement in 2012 SSAS tabular using DAX. As 2012 has not introduced SWITCH statement.

My question:

```
MeasureZ := IF(VALUES(Store[Close]) = "Y", MeasureX, MeasureY)
```

The above calculations returns values when I select `"close" = "Y" or "N"`, if I select both its giving `"a table of multiple values was supplied" error`. Pls help me with this

Comment: What is your desired outcome when both are selected?  The sum of `MeasureX` and `MeasureY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a filter applied to `Store[Close]` of all of the values from this column will be returned by `VALUES`, leading to the error you received.  Use `FIRSTNONBLANK` instead, which as the name implies returns the first value of the column in the current context that isn't blank.

```
[MeasureZ ]: =
        IF (
            FIRSTNONBLANK ( Store[Close], 1 ) = "Y",
            [MeasureX],
            [MeasureY]
        )
```